# Unable to load layer default style from MSSQL database

Tags: pyqgis, style, sql-server

I have a point layer in MSSQL database that has a relation with a polygon layer that is also stored in the same database. Both layers have default styles stored in layer_styles table in the same database and those default layer styles have the same names as the mentioned two layers. When I load the point layer, the polygon layer loads automatically. It loads without the default style and I am unable to either restore the default style or load the default style manually because there are no related styles shown in the settings menu.

[image: Database Styles Manager after automatically loading polygon layer as related layer to the Point layer]

When I remove the automatically loaded polygon layer and add it manually, the default style is loaded without hiccups and I can restore the default style or load it without any problems.

[image: Database Styles Manager after manually loading polygon layer]

I am failing to understand why is this happening. I tried to load the polygon layer and its default style via PyQGis script:

```
if QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(TABLE_NAME):
    sonde = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(TABLE_NAME)[0]
    styles = sonde.listStylesInDatabase()
    sonde.loadNamedStyle(styles[2][0])
    sonde.triggerRepaint()
else:
    URI: str = f'dbname={DB_NAME} host={HOST_NAME} user={USER_NAME} password={PASS} 
    estimatedmetadata=true srid=0 disableInvalidGeometryHandling=\'0\' table="dbo"."         
    {TABLE_NAME}"'
    sonde = QgsVectorLayer(URI, TABLE_NAME, "mssql")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(sonde)
    styles = sonde.listStylesInDatabase()
    sonde.loadNamedStyle(styles[2][0])
    sonde.triggerRepaint()
```

This script works only if I manually load the polygon layer. Then the default style can be changed/restored. If the layer is loaded via PyQGis, the default style cannot be applied, the same behavior as when the polygon layer is loaded by relation.